# Button not working in email when sending email via nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

Im sending a simple email via node mailer.

But i can't seem to make the **href** work, when I click the button in the email it doesn't go anywhere.

```
  const link = `http://localhost:3000/reset-password/${user._id}/${token}`;
  const output = `
    <h1>You have requasted an password rest. Follow the above link to reset password</h1>
    <button><a href="${link}">Click here</a></button>
    <h3>This is a test</h3>   
  `;

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    },
  });

  // Step 2
  let mailOptions = {
    from: "SOME_EMAIL",
    to: user.email, // TODO: email receiver
    subject: "Password Reset",
    html: output,
  };
```

When I inspect that html in the email, it seems that the HREF doesnt render

Comment: have you tried replacing the link with another placeholder url, like `https://www.google.com/`? i suspect your email provider filters out invalid/insecure links like `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: @deecue yes is tried this already

Comment: can you show us how does the html look like in the email? btw, from this source (https://www.reddit.com/r/HTML/comments/lsky98/psa_you_cannot_nest_interactive_elements/) by standard, it seems like you cannot nest <a> inside a <button>, but i am not sure if nodemailer or google did some linting that breaks your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
const link = `http://localhost:3000/reset-password/${user._id}/${token}`;
  const output = `
    <h1>You have requasted an password rest. Follow the above link to reset password</h1>
    <a href="${link}">Click here</a>
    <h3>This is a test</h3>   
  `;

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD
    },
  });

  // Step 2
  let mailOptions = {
    from: "SOME_EMAIL",
    to: user.email, // TODO: email receiver
    subject: "Password Reset",
    html: output,
  };
```

This code will work fine.
Using a tag inside a button tag doesn't work.
This is why Outlook email supports href event, but not onclick event for html.